# How to search a file in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm

1. Eclipse has this feature where you can *search any file in your folder*. Is there any such feature in PhpStorm?
2. Is there a shortcut for indentation and how can I customize that?

Googled it, but no results.

Comment: @zzlalani:you can check if you want,there are no results for searching file..

Comment: and when I searched it `how to search a keyword in file in phpstorm?` https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+search+a+keyword+in+file+in+phpstorm%3F&oq=how+to+search+a+keyword+in+file+in+phpstorm%3F&aqs=chrome.0.57.6771j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: In the bottom they says `Note: Use Ctrl+Shift+F and Ctrl+Shift+R to toggle between the Find In Path and Replace In Path dialog boxes`

Comment: @zzlalani, He wants to search the files not the content inside the files.

Comment: Did you want to search FOR a file, or search the contents of all files within a folder?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

From the Menu of PHPStorm Choose **Navigate** -> **File** or use the shortcut <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> or <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> (as per the edit). Type the required file name you want to search. Done.

**Screenshot for your understanding.**

[image]

Comment: Check the screenshot. Which version you got ?

Comment: mine is ctrl+shift+N,got it

Comment: Good. what is your version by the way.?

Comment: 5.0.3 it is....do you know some more features that make your work super easy...just started using php storm..

Comment: `Find in Path` is really helpful in finding whichever text you want. Also it supports CTRL+CLICK function navigation which is the best !

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35976/discussion-between-vagabond-and-shankar-damodaran)

Comment: Its worth noticing, that you can select multiple files with ctrl or shift and mouse click.

Comment: `SHIFT` + `CMD` + `O`

Answer (score 48):

In **Phpstorm version 7.1.2** you need to go to 
**Navigate -> File...**
or press **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>**

Answer (score 11):

Ctrl+Shift+N - search in whole project, that is minus. If you need to search in some specific folder, you can use the "File mask:"

Press Ctrl+Shift+N and in the right top corner you will have this field. 
Look at the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

1. On the main menu, choose **Edit | Find | Find in Path**, or press **Ctrl+Shift+F**
   (see http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html)
2. On the main menu, choose **Code | Reformat Code**, or press **Ctrl+Alt+L**
   (see http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/reformatting-source-code.html)

Comment: first is not working..i want to find a specific file(not some text in a file..u misunderstood) in same or other folder/project and open it..like in dreamweaver??

Answer (score 2):

Another and easy way would be to press double Shift on Linux or Windows. It would open a search bar and from there select file. More over exact short cut can be found(as told above) by Nagivigation>Find.