# PhpStorm failed to find file

Tags: phpstorm

PhpStorm 2021.1.1
Mac M1 11.3

When I try to find file using `Cmd+Shift+O`, or `Navigate | File..`, PhpStorm failed to find the file. It seems trying to search file from `/Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents` directory, rather than search in the project directory.

I tried to `File | Invalidate Caches`, no luck. Can any body help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18372961/how-to-search-a-file-in-phpstorm

Comment: Try providing screenshots (better a screencast/video) of the search and the whole IDE window: maybe it will give some clues. *"It seems trying to search file from `/Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents` directory"* This obviously looks wrong. Does it behave the same in another project? etc

Comment: @LazyOne I was in a hurry, so I recreated the project from git source, and it works. Other projects behaviors fine. I guess phpstorm doesn't consider this project (previously good in  phpstorm) as a project — take it as file opened outside of a project.

Comment: @Nick Must have been the project settings file corruption so the IDE thinks that the whole folder is outside of the project (can be caused by hard computer shutdown/crash; the same for the app; maybe some another reason (e.g. file permissions / security software / AV)). The usual advice for such case: delete the `.idea` subfolder for such project while IDE is closed (back it up first if so desired); then use "Open" and point to the the project root folder -- IDE will create a new project from those files.

Comment: If it now works then great: consider making your own answer: will help other users in a similar situation and having an accepted answer will make it more visible.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by:

1. Delete project.
2. Start a new project by pulling code from the git repo.

I also noticed that after starting the new project, PhpStorm `Git | Update Project` runs much faster.

Thanks for @LazyOne's answer. I remembered that before this happened, I upgraded macOS to 11.3. Perhaps this caused the project directory to corrupt.

(Previously I also tried to delete .idea, hoping PhpStorm would rebuild the index. However, mistake is mine that I didn't quit phpstorm during deleting .idea.)